# Find all Real string in file [Regex]

Tags: regex

I Have a encrypting txt file with digits [��R��m����r�8�b9l�ruӫz��]
in the file have also strings like username and more.
I need Regex to find all that strings whitout the symbols.
I tried lots of options and its faild..
please Help..
Thanks !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the regex engine you use, you will need to search for the unicode FFFD, like `^((?!\x{FFFD}).)*$`